# Where could I find the source code of UIStoryboardSegue.swift

Tags: swift3, xcode8, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I've been struggling to find examples to implement custom unwind segues that would work with Xcode 10 and Swift 3. I thought looking into the source code would give me a clue.

Unfortunately, I don't even know where to find it (searched my macbook and googling)! Where could I find this file?

**EDIT**

**Solved**, see comment & answer below, UIStoryboardSeague.swift is part of UIKit and it is not open source.

Comment: The `UIStoryboardSegue` is part of `UIKit`. `UIKit` is not open source.

Comment: Ah, no wonder, I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIStoryboardSegue` is part of `UIKit`. `UIKit` is not open source.